# How to use refresh token in Get request once actual token expired in Python

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, microsoft-graph-api, refresh-token

I have a scenario where I need to connect Onedrive and get all folders and inside files information, so for that I registered app in Azure to get  tenant id and client id etc.

I'm successfully logged in and able to get folders and files information, but I have have around 8k+ folders and inside files so I'm getting token expire time after 1 to 2 hours getting that error. I have refresh token also but not sure how can I use that token in GET request.

Here I'm pasting the code; can anyone please suggest how to use that? In my code I'm creating bin file in that have both `access_token` and `refresh_token`:

```
TENANT_ID = '111*********f5d4'
CLIENT_ID = '7c0*************5517'

AUTHORITY = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + TENANT_ID
ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'
base_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/'
SCOPES = [
    'Files.ReadWrite.All',
    'Sites.ReadWrite.All',
    'User.Read',
    'User.ReadBasic.All'
]

cache = msal.SerializableTokenCache()

if os.path.exists('token_cache.bin'):
    cache.deserialize(open('token_cache.bin', 'r').read())

atexit.register(lambda: open('token_cache.bin', 'w').write(cache.serialize()) if cache.has_state_changed else None)

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(CLIENT_ID, authority=AUTHORITY, token_cache=cache)

accounts = app.get_accounts()
result = None
if len(accounts) > 0:
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(SCOPES, account=accounts[0])

if result is None:
    flow = app.initiate_device_flow(scopes=SCOPES)
    if 'user_code' not in flow:
        raise Exception('Failed to create device flow')

    print(flow['message'])

    result = app.acquire_token_by_device_flow(flow)

if 'access_token' in result:
    parent = base_url +'/drives/!FJ9b********************BnEOcC-mq/root:/Box_Migration/Product Images - SHARE'
    link = parent+":/children"
    while True:
        rGetCh = requests.get(link, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']})
        data=rGetCh.json()['value']
        for itemm in data:
            file_id =itemm['name']
            print(file_id)
            endpoint=base_url + f'/drives/b!FJ9b********************BnEOcC-mq/root:/Box_Migration/****uct I888ages - SHARE/{file_id}:/children'
            response_data= requests.get(endpoint,headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result['access_token']})
            print(response_data)
            json_data =response_data.json()
            #print(json_data)
       
            with open('new_Refresh_token.json', 'a+') as fout:
                fout.write(json.dumps(json_data,indent = 4,default=str))
                fout.write(',\n')
                fout.close()       
        for ch in rGetCh.json()["value"]:
            # Looping through the current list of children
            chName = urllib.parse.quote(ch["name"].encode('utf8'))
            chPath = parent + "/" + chName

        if "@odata.nextLink" in rGetCh.json():  # if this is in the response, there are more children
            link =  rGetCh.json()["@odata.nextLink"]
        else:
           break

else:
    raise Exception('no access token in result')
```

Here we have two GET request one for to get folders information and other for file information.

Please can any one suggest/help/idea?

Answer (score 1):

If token expired. Then take a list of folders half one time and second half other time
Store one variable and run

Comment: Hi, welcome on StackOverflow. Could you add more context and information to the answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).